# angular-datatables : How to remove "Show N entries" but leave pagination

Tags: angular-datatables

There is a project that uses angular-datatables. Now I need to remove "Show N entries" dropdown from a page with such table, but leave pagination untouched. For now i've found this way -

```js
withOption('paging', false)
```

but this removes both!

Can anyone show me better way than just to remove them from DOM manually?

Answer (score 5):

Yes - `paging` removes both since there is no need for showing the lengthmenu if the table not is paginated. Use the [**`lengthChange`**](https://datatables.net/reference/option/lengthChange) option to control whether the lengthmenu should be visible or not :

```js
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
                   .withOption('lengthChange', false);
```

demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/0PnEwohCF9348uAf6OSD?p=preview**

Comment: any idea of how to show 'Show N entries on bottom?'

Answer (score 0):

> Yes - `paging` removes both since there is no need for showing the
>   lengthmenu if the table not is paginated. Use the
>   [**`lengthChange`**][1] option to control whether the lengthmenu
>   should be visible or not :
>
> ```js
> $scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
>                    .withOption('lengthChange', false);
> ```
>
> demo -> **http://plnkr.co/edit/TKMyZ1CLvDUazGGImiCd?p=preview**
>
> [1]: https://datatables.net/reference/option/lengthChange

it's still there.

```
vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withPaginationType('full_numbers')
                                                    .withDisplayLength(10)
                                                    .withOption('lengthChange', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

You try add follow option to dtOptions:

```
.withLanguage({
            "sInfoFiltered": ""
        })
```