# How to hide lengthChange in Angular-Datatables?

Tags: angularjs, datatables, angular-datatables

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCbHx.jpg)

I want to remove that filter for rows.
I already tried

```
vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withPaginationType('full_numbers')
                                        .withDisplayLength(10)
                                        .withOption('language', lang);
var lang = {
 "lengthMenu": ""
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [angular-datatables : How to remove “Show N entries” but leave pagination](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32894201/angular-datatables-how-to-remove-show-n-entries-but-leave-pagination)

Comment: it is still there.

Comment: here is my code

vm.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withPaginationType('full_numbers')
                                                        .withDisplayLength(10)
                                                        .withOption('lengthChange', false);

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve the same,

1. Using 'lengthChange' option.

   ```
   DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
       .withOption('lengthChange', false);
   ```
2. Using 'dom' option.

   ```
   DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions()
       .withOption('dom', 'frtip');
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the `dom` option? You may need to exclude the `l` option. [DataTables dom Option](https://datatables.net/reference/option/dom)